# Swift 3, Sort an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: swift3

I'm having a heck of a time in Swift 3 sorting an array of dictionaries.

In Swift 2, I would do it this way, which worked fine:

```
var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
let dic1 = ["last": "Smith", "first": "Robert"]
dicArray.append(dic1)
let dic2 = ["last": "Adams", "first": "Bill"]
dicArray.append(dic2)
let sortedArray = dicArray.sort { ($0["last"] as? String) < ($1["last"] as? String) }
```

Converting the same code to Swift 3 has not gone well. The system guided me to this (through a circuitous route):

```
let sortedArray = dicArray.sorted { ($0["last"]! as String) < ($1["last"]! as String) }
```

But the app always crashes, with the error that it found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

After banging my head against the table for too long, putting ?s and !s in every imaginable combination, I resorted to an old approach to get the job done:

```
let sortedArray = (dicArray as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "last", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

That works, and I'm moving along, but it's not very Swifty, is it?

Where did it all go wrong? How can I make the pure Swift sort function work in a case like this?

Comment: If you have a static set of keys, you should definitely use a struct rather than a dict.

Comment: As @Alexander writes, use a struct: if the keys are _not_ static, the sorting above is very fragile w.r.t. runtime safety, and it should be verified that all dictionaries in the arrays of dictionaries indeed does contain the key `"last"`, e.g. checking such that `dicArray.contains(where: { !$0.keys.contains("last") })` is not `true`. If you had incorporated such a guard in the first place, you would've caught the empty additional dictionary, as this would've violated the the input verification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Where did it all go wrong?

It went wrong on your first line:

```
var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

That *never* did what you want, even in Swift 2, because you are actually inserting an extra, empty dictionary into the array. That's where the crash comes from; the empty dictionary has no `"last"` key, because it is, uh, empty.

You want this:

```
var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

See the difference? After that change, everything falls into place:

```
var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
let dic1 = ["last": "Smith", "first": "Robert"]
dicArray.append(dic1)
let dic2 = ["last": "Adams", "first": "Bill"]
dicArray.append(dic2)
let sortedArray = dicArray.sorted {$0["last"]! < $1["last"]!}
// [["first": "Bill", "last": "Adams"], ["first": "Robert", "last": "Smith"]]
```

Comment: I can't believe I did that. Good eye. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using dictionaries with a fixed set of keys, it's generally advisable to create your own custom types:

```
struct Person {
    let lastName: String
    let firstName: String
}
```

This way, you never have to worry about whether you got the key for a particular value in a dictionary right, because the compiler will enforce checks for the names of the property. It makes it easier to write robust, error-free code.

And, coincidentally, it makes sorting cleaner, too. To make this custom type sortable, you make it conform to the `Comparable` protocol:

```
extension Person: Comparable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName && lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName
    }

    public static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        // if lastnames are the same, compare first names, 
        // otherwise we're comparing last names

        if lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName {
            return lhs.firstName < rhs.firstName
        } else {
            return lhs.lastName < rhs.lastName
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can just sort them, keeping the comparison logic nicely encapsulated within the `Person` type:

```
let people = [Person(lastName: "Smith", firstName: "Robert"), Person(lastName: "Adams", firstName: "Bill")]
let sortedPeople = people.sorted()
```

---

Now, admittedly, the above dodges your implicit question of how to compare optionals. So, below is an example where `firstName` and `lastName` are optionals. But, rather than worrying about where to put the `?` or `!`, I'd use `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`, or a `switch` statement, e.g.:

```
struct Person {
    let lastName: String?
    let firstName: String?
}

extension Person: Comparable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName && lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName
    }

    public static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        // if lastnames are the same, compare first names, 
        // otherwise we're comparing last names

        var lhsString: String?
        var rhsString: String?
        if lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName {
            lhsString = lhs.firstName
            rhsString = rhs.firstName
        } else {
            lhsString = lhs.lastName
            rhsString = rhs.lastName
        }

        // now compare two optional strings

        return (lhsString ?? "") < (rhsString ?? "")

        // or you could do
        // 
        // switch (lhsString, rhsString) {
        // case (nil, nil): return false
        // case (nil, _): return true
        // case (_, nil): return false
        // default: return lhsString! < rhsString!
        // }
    }
}
```

The `switch` statement is more explicit regarding the handling of `nil` values (e.g. `nil` sorted before or after non-optional values) and will distinguish between a `nil` value and an empty string, should you need that. The `nil` coalescing operator is simpler (and IMHO, more intuitive for the end-user), but you can use `switch` approach if you want.

Comment: this is more than just answer, thanks for sharing the knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor =  NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "YOUR KEY", ascending: true)

let sortedResults: NSArray = tempArray.sortedArray(using: [descriptor]) as NSArray